# Modelsim Altera not working

Tags: verilog, simulation, hdl

Hi i'm new to verilog designing and i'm trying to simulate but modelsim doesn't even load the design, i'm glad if someone could help, thanks.
( counter and contatore are two modules that i included in the main design )

```
module luci (input reset, input clk, input sw, output reg [7:0] led);
wire a,b;
assign b = out==0? 1 : 0;
reg c = 0;
reg g = 0;
wire [6:0] out;
counter contador (clk,reset,sw,1'b1,,a);
contatore shift (clk,reset,a,b,,out);

always@(a) begin
    g <= g + 1;
    if (c==0) begin
         case(out)
              7'b0000000 : led = 8'b00000001;
                7'b0000001 : led = 8'b00000010;
                7'b0000010 : led = 8'b00000100;
                7'b0000100 : led = 8'b00001000;
                7'b0001000 : led = 8'b00010000;
                7'b0010000 : led = 8'b00100000;
                7'b0100000 : led = 8'b01000000;
                7'b1000000 : led = 8'b10000000;
                endcase
                end
     else begin
         case(out)
              7'b0000000 : led = 8'b01000000;
                7'b0000001 : led = 8'b00100000;
                7'b0000010 : led = 8'b00010000;
                7'b0000100 : led = 8'b00001000;
                7'b0001000 : led = 8'b00000100;
                7'b0010000 : led = 8'b00000010;
               endcase
            end
            if ( g==8 & c==0)begin
               c <=1;
                g <= 0;
                end
                
            if ( g == 6 & c==1) begin
               c<=0;
                g<=0;
                end
                
end
endmodule
```

TESTBENCH

```
timescale 1ns/1ps

module tb_luci();

reg clock;
reg res;
reg sew;
wire [7:0] out;

luci  #i1 (.reset(res),.clk(clock),.sw(sew),.led(out));

initial
   begin
        res = 1'b1;
         sew = 1'b1;
         #(T*2)
         $stop;
         end

always
  begin
  #(T/2) CLK <= ~CLK;
  end
endmodule
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the transcript to see if it actually compiled?

Comment: yep, first check for the thing being correct, verilog-wise. Also, you should use your IDE's "format code" functionality to fix your wildly varying indentations. It's pretty likely that there's structural bugs hiding in there if you're a beginner and don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Questa (aka Modelsim) gives several compile errors on eda playground

```
QuestaSim-64 vlog 2021.3_1 Compiler 2021.08 Aug 15 2021
Start time: 11:27:55 on Apr 22,2022
vlog -writetoplevels questa.tops -timescale 1ns/1ns design.sv testbench.sv 
-- Compiling module luci
** Error: design.sv(4): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'out'.
** Error (suppressible): design.sv(7): (vlog-2388) 'out' already declared in this scope (luci) at design.sv(4).
-- Compiling module tb_luci
** Error: testbench.sv(16): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'T'.
** Error: testbench.sv(22): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'T'.
** Error: testbench.sv(22): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'CLK'.
End time: 11:27:55 on Apr 22,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 5, Warnings: 0
```

Would be surprised if this compiles for you.